# Select time windows and sliding time windows

Tags: hana

I'm looking for a solution with good performance for my following problem:

I have two tables

1. Event Table `EVENT` containing a event and the date of this event
2. Temperature Table `TEMP_TABLE` containing a date (sequential over 365 days beginning bye 2015-01-01) and a value

The first I want to do is to select all values 5 days or less days before a event into a separate table and also fill the columns for `eventNumber` and `daysBeforeEvent`

```
| eventNumber| dayBeforeEv | value        |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          | 1           |     -1       |
| 1          | 2           |     21       |
| 1          | 3           |     15       |
| 1          | 4           |     7        |
| 1          | 5           |     -7       |
| 2          | 1           |     -9       |
| 2          | 2           |     12       |
| 2          | 3           |     1        |
| 2          | 4           |     -7       |
| 2          | 5           |     8        |
| 3          | 1           |     18       |
| ...        | ...         |     ...      |
```

In a second table I want to select all values for the time between events in same structure. Just I want to use here a kind of sliding window.

```
Day     |1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6  |7  |8  |9  |10 |
Event   |X  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |X  |
```

First window will be from day 2 to day 6

Then the window will be moved by one day and the second window will be from day 3 to day 7 etc.

If there will be an event the window will become shorter e.g. from day 6 to day 9 (4 days, next one will include only 3 days)

I use now following solution:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;

WHILE @cnt <= 5
BEGIN
    
INSERT INTO "RESULT" ("EVENT_NUM","EVENT_ID","VALUE","DATE") 
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "DATE" ASC) AS ROW,@cnt,"VALUE","DATE" FROM "TEMP_TABLE" 
WHERE "DATE" IN (SELECT DATEADD(day,@cnt*-1,"DATE") FROM "EVENT" ORDER BY "DATE" ASC);

SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;

END;
```

It works fine until there are no dates missing in `TEMP_TABLE`. But when there is a gap (e.g. I have entry on 2016-02-01 and 2016-02-03 so the 2016-02-02 is missing)

Comment: So far I just having idea how it could be solved. But I'm not sure if there is any better way. I would use a method with nested loops. Iterate over the table with event and in a second loop iterate over the time window. For the 2. Problem I would just move then the window iterative by one day

Comment: You should edit your question and add your nested loop solution so that people can help debug it or offer alternative suggestions.

Comment: is this Oracle?  `ADD_DAYS` ?

Comment: Sorry, SAP-HANA, I corrected it

Comment: So just the EVENT_NUM isn't anymore correct

Answer (score 0):

Please modify this pseudo answer to show us the desired result. I think it covers the first part of your question, but the "window" of the second part is still unclear.

```
declare @Event table (EventId int primary key, EventDate datetime, EventDesc varchar(100));
insert into @Event
    select 1, '2015-10-15', 'Event 1' union all
    select 2, '2015-11-15', 'Event 2'

declare @Temp table (TempDate datetime primary key, TempValue int);
insert into @Temp
    select  '2015-10-12', -1 union all
    select  '2015-10-11', 21 union all
    select  '2015-11-14', 14

declare @Numbers table (N int primary key);
insert into @Numbers
    select 1 union all
    select 2 union all
    select 3 union all
    select 4 union all
    select 5;

with stage as
(   select  EventId,
            EventDate,
            EventDesc, 
            [DaysBeforeEv] = n.n-1,
            [ThisDate] = dateadd(day, -(n.n-1), EventDate)
    from    @Event
    cross
    apply   @Numbers n
    where   n.n <= 5
)
select  *
from    stage s
left
join    @Temp t on 
        s.ThisDate = t.TempDate
order
by      s.EventId, s.ThisDate desc
```

Comment: I posted one solution up but there are still some problems with